# php pdp how to use foreach to fetch data and display them into a form

Tags: php, pdo, prepared-statement

I am using PDO connection and a `foreach loop` to fetch data and display them into a form in order to allow a user to see the entered data. in the PHP code below I do use `prepared statement` to attempt to retrieve the data
here is the php code

```
    <?php

    /**
     * Simple wrapper around htmlspecialchars() that always passes the correct require options
     *
     * @param string $str
     * @return string
     */
    function html($str)
    {
        return htmlspecialchars($str, ENT_COMPAT | ENT_HTML5, 'utf-8');
    }

    error_reporting(-1);
    ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

    $servername = "xxx";
    $username = "xxxxx";
    $password = "xxxxx";
    $dbname= "xxxxx";
    $charset = 'utf8';
    $options = [
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
    ];

    $dsn = sprintf('mysql:host=%s;dbname=%s;charset=%s', $servername, $dbname, $charset);



    try {
        $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
    $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT id, cognome, indirizzo FROM req_table");
        $rows = $sth->execute()->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    $errorCode = $e->getCode();

        exit("Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage());
    }

    ?>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Form</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <form action="req.php" method="post">
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td>Nome</td>
              <td><input type="text" name="nome"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Cognome</td>
              <td>
                <select name="cognome">
    <?php while ($row = $rows->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) { ?>
              <option value="<?= $row['id'] ?>"><?= html($row['cognome']) ?></option>
<?php } ?>

                </select>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Indirizzo</td>
              <td>
                <select name="indirizzo">
    <select name="indirizzo">
<?php while ($row = $rows->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) { ?>
              <option value="<?= $row['id'] ?>"><?= html($row['indirizzo']) ?></option>
<?php } ?>

                </select>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="2" style="text-align: center;">
                <input type="submit" name="Invia" value="Submit" />
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </form>
      </body>
    </html>
```

I really hope the above code is clear enough for you to tell me what solution can be found in order to fix this problem

**CODE EDIT**
    error inside `try/catch`

first edit

```
catch(PDOException $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage();
$errorCode = $e->getCode();
exit("Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage());
}
```

second edit

```
$rows = $sth->execute();
```

third edit

```
<?php while ($row = $rows->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) { ?>
          <option value="<?= $row['id'] ?>"><?= html($row['cognome']) ?></option>
<?php } ?>
```

and now 500 server error and a blank page 
**PS** `error reporting` is enabled and I have replaced `foreach` with `while loop`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any time you get the...

> *"Fatal error: Call to a member function..."*

...it is likely because there is an issue with your query. The `prepare()` might return `FALSE` (a Boolean), but this generic failure message doesn't leave you much in the way of clues. How do you find out what is wrong with your query? You *ask*!

First of all, make sure error reporting is turned on and visible: add these two lines to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

If your error reporting has been set in the php.ini you won't have to worry about this. Just make sure you handle errors gracefully and never reveal the true cause of any issues to your users. Revealing the true cause to the public can be a gold engraved invitation for those wanting to harm your sites and servers. If you do not want to send errors to the browser you can always monitor your web server error logs. Log locations will vary from server to server e.g., on Ubuntu the error log is typically located at `/var/log/apache2/error.log`. If you're examining error logs in a Linux environment you can use `tail -f /path/to/log` in a console window to see errors as they occur in real-time....or as you make them.

Once you're squared away on standard error reporting adding error checking on your database connection and queries will give you much more detail about the problems going on. Have a look at this example where the column name is incorrect. First, the code which returns the generic fatal error message:

```
$sql = "SELECT `foo` FROM `weird_words` WHERE `definition` = ?";
$query = $mysqli->prepare($sql)); // assuming $mysqli is the connection
$query->bind_param('s', $definition);
$query->execute();
```

The error is generic and not very helpful to you in solving what is going on.

With a couple of more lines of code you can get very detailed information which you can use to solve the issue *immediately*. Check the `prepare()` statement for truthiness and if it is good you can proceed on to binding and executing.

```
$sql = "SELECT `foo` FROM `weird_words` WHERE `definition` = ?";
if($query = $mysqli->prepare($sql)) { // assuming $mysqli is the connection
    $query->bind_param('s', $definition);
    $query->execute();
    // any additional code you need would go here.
} else {
    $error = $mysqli->errno . ' ' . $mysqli->error;
    echo $error; // 1054 Unknown column 'foo' in 'field list'
}
```

If something is wrong you can spit out an error message which takes you directly to the issue. In this case there is no `foo` column in the table, solving the problem is trivial.

If you choose, you can include this checking in a function or class and extend it by handling the errors gracefully as mentioned previously.

Comment: i am using `pdo` not `mysqli` and anyway `error reporting` is enabled otherwise I would not have been able to tell you what is wrong with my code

Comment: It doesn't matter which API you're using. Your query is not returning anything, consequently your database object does not exist.

Comment: so what is your final suggestion my friend? I have paid extremely attention to your answer however I am allowed to tell you that I have found it too much an abstrac, no offence you helped me to better understand what I am wrong but still it is a bit unclear

Comment: Add error checking to your database connection. See the example [here](http://www.jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html) where the connection is placed in a `try/catch` statement.

Comment: added the error inside the `try/catch` now a 500 server error occured after editing something inside my code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85207/discussion-between-riccardo990-and-jay-blanchard).

Comment: Apologies, I am not able to chat from this location @Riccardo990

Comment: so please give me a second and I will show you the edits

Comment: did you understand what I did?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to use `execute()`

Try this:

```
$rows = $sth->execute()->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Nevertheless, using `fetchAll()` in order to use a `foreach()` loop after that is useless. So replace this:

```
$rows = $sth->execute()->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

by this:

```
$rows = $sth->execute();
```

and within your HTML, replace this:

```
<?php 
foreach ($rows as $row) { ?>
    <option value="<?= $row['id'] ?>"><?= html($row['cognome']) ?></option>
<?php } ?>
```

by this:

```
<?php 
while($row = $rows->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) { ?>
    <option value="<?= $row['id'] ?>"><?= html($row['cognome']) ?></option>
<?php }?>
```

Comment: could I ask you why you prefere `while loop` rrather then `foreach`?

Comment: I have tried your suggestions and now I have a 500 server error and I am quite sure this is because of a syntax error